# Solve differential equations containing $x''$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation $$x'' + 3x' = 20e^{2t}$$ if $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 1$.

I am pretty sure $x$ must contain $e^{2t}$, but other than that, I'm not really sure how to proceed from here. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Can you solve the homogenous equation?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Ellefsen Hmm so that gives me $x' = Ce^{-3x}$?

Comment: Correct. Integrate to find $x$, then remember we get nice linear algebra when our summands are all of the form $f(t)x^{(n)}$, so the general solution is the sum of the homogenous solution plus a particular solution (think of solving $Ax = 0$ vs $Ax = b$ in linear algebra)

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Put $y=x'$. The homogeneous  equation becomes $y'+3y=0$ whose solution is $y=ae^{-3t}$. Integrate to get $x$. A particular solution of the type $ce^{2t}$ exists. Add the particular solution to the general solution of the homogeneous  equation and the apply the intial conditions.

Answer: $e^{-3t}-3+2e^{2t}$.

Comment: so from the first steps you mentioned, I get that $x = -\frac{a}{3} e^{-3t} + c$—is this right?

Comment: Yes, now proceed. @singularity

Answer (score 1):

You could use Laplace transform to solve a Cauchy problem like this.
First apply the Laplace transform to the equation:

$$x'' + 3x' = 20e^{2t}\Rightarrow \mathcal{L}\{x''(t)+3x'(t)\}(s)=\mathcal{L}\{20e^{2t}\}(s)$$

You will get

$$s^2\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)+3s\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}(s)-3x(0)=\frac{20}{s-2}$$

Since you know the values of $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$, you can solve the equation to $x(t)$:

$$s^2\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}(s)-1+3s\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}(s)=\frac{20}{s-2}\Rightarrow$$

$$\Rightarrow x(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left(\frac{22-s}{s(s+3)(s-2)}\right)$$

Now, decompose the fraction into simple ones and apply the Laplace inverse transform to those. You will get the result. To me, this is the best way to solve a linear equation with initial conditions (when the Laplace transform of the functions is known), since you don't have to use neither the Undetermined coefficients method nor the Variation of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

$$x'' + 3x' = 20e^{2t}\implies (D^2 + 3D)x = 20e^{2t}\tag1$$where $~D=\dfrac{dx}{dt}~$.

Let $~x=Ae^{mt}~$be a solution of the equation $(1)~$.

Auxiliary equation is $$m^2+3m=0\implies m=0,-3$$
Solution of the Homogeneous equation of $(1)$ i.e., of $~(D^2 + 3D)x =0~$ is $$x=c_1~+c_2~e^{-3t}$$where $~c_1,~c_2~$are constants.

So the Complementary Function  (C.F.) of equation $(1)$ is $$c_1~+c_2~e^{-3t}$$where $~c_1,~c_2~$are constants.

Particular Integral (P.I.)

$~~~=~\dfrac{1}{D^2 + 3D}~20e^{2t}$

$~~~=20~e^{2t}~\dfrac{1}{2^2 + 3\cdot2}$

$~~~=2~e^{2t}$

So the general solution of equation $(1)$ is $$x=c_1~+c_2~e^{-3t}+2~e^{2t}$$where $~c_1,~c_2~$are constants.

If $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 1~$, then $~c_1=-3~$and $~c_2=1~$.

So the p[articular solution is $$x=-3~+e^{-3t}+2~e^{2t}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Try your assumption ! With $x=e^{2t}$, you have

$$4e^{2t}+3\cdot2e^{2t}\stackrel?=20 e^{2t},$$ which is correct to a constant factor. This gives you a particular solution.

---

Now if you add another exponential, let $x=e^{at}+?e^{2t}$,

$$(a^2+3a)e^{at}+10\,?e^{2t}=20e^{2t},$$

you have an identity when $a(a+3)=0.$

Now up to you to find the particular solution that fulfills the initial conditions.

Answer (score -1):

For your work: The solution is given by $$x(t)=-\frac{1}{3} c_1 e^{-3 t}+c_2+2 e^{2 t}$$

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question *“... **how** to proceed from here.”*